# Wagtail Forms: Validator that compares two email fields

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am creating a form using Wagtail Forms, and I would like to add a couple of email fields, and compare them to make sure the user is not submitting the same email address twice. How would I go about this?

Comment: what have you tried? can you add the code?

Comment: Wagtailforms is not a replacement for Django’s form support. It is designed as a way for page authors to build general-purpose data collection forms without having to write code. Are you better off using a regular Django form? What is your motivation to use wagtail.contrib.forms? What have you tried?